# Custom textfield inside a cell text is blank when Ui Tableview Scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]I am using a table view inside a view controller.In  My table view multiple sections, and section=0 is custom text fields when scroll table view then text field cell text is overlap or blank, how to resolve
my code is given below

[image]

```
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        let cellidentifier="cell1"
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellidentifier,for:indexPath as IndexPath)  as! TextfieldTableViewCell

             cell.main_textfield_hieght.constant = CGFloat(main_tf_height)
            cell.main_textfield_leading.constant = CGFloat(main_tf_leading)
            cell.main_textfield_trailing.constant = CGFloat(main_tf_trailing)
            cell.main_textfield_width.constant = CGFloat(main_tf_width)


        let object:BaseClass = arr_baseclass[indexPath.row]
        cell.text_field.placeholder = object.fieldName
        cell.text_field.tag=indexPath.row+1
       cell.text_field.delegate=self
        return cell
    }
```

In given screen shot  I have entered text Ist field after scroll position mismatch

Comment: self.layoutIfNeeded after update constraints and one more thing after reuse cell you need to assign text again in cell for row otherwise it will always blank

Comment: When you are writing any `if` conditions inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you should write it's `else` condition too, otherwise `tableView` always behave strangely. It happens because the of `reusing` of tableView cells.

Comment: In `cellForRow`, depending on the position you need to set text in each cell from your model or if text doesn't exist, set it to empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a array of textFields and to append the textfields when cells are created.

```
var arrOfTxtFields:[UITextField] = []
```

Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` remove all subviews.

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
       let cellidentifier="cell1"
       let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellidentifier,for:indexPath as IndexPath)  as! TextfieldTableViewCell
       for subview in cell.contentView.subviews
       {
       subview.removeFromSuperview()
       }
       if arrOfTxtFields.indices.contains(indexPath.row)
       {
          cell.addSubview(arrOfTxtFields[indexPath.row])
       }
       else
       {
       let object:BaseClass = arr_baseclass[indexPath.row]
       cell.text_field.placeholder = object.fieldName
       cell.text_field.tag=indexPath.row+1
       cell.text_field.delegate=self
       arrOfTxtFields.append(cell.text_field)
       }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: But I have maintain text of text fields and my text fields is custom class TextfieldTableViewCell

Comment: When you save a textField in an array then the text, placeholder, tag of the textFields will be maintained. Try it.

Comment: var arrOfTxtFields:[UITextField] =[]

Comment: textfield is created inside cell in tableview from storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if text field over lap data

```
    let subViews = cell.contentView.subviews
    for subview in subViews
    {
      if (subview is UITextField) 
       { 
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
      }  
    }
```

Comment: Have you get subview from cell

Comment: yes, but my problem is when scroll table view  then again move section 0 text field text is blank or overlapped

Comment: Yes this problem occurred when you scroll table because you cell is not make and data overlapped. You should remove   for subview in subViews
    {  subview.removeFromSuperview. }.

Comment: But I maintain the text field data also

Comment: let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellidentifier,for: indexPath)  as! TextfieldTableViewCell  and after check cell subview

Comment: if I check cell subview and subview.removeFromSuperview() then all textfild remove screen is blank